# Wpf Xaml - TreeView Hierarchical Data Templates - multiple item sources

Tags: wpf, treeview, controls

I have a class like this (describes class in C# and its fields, methods and so on):

```
public class CSharpType
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }  
    public List<CSharpMethod> Methods { get; private set; }
    public List<CSharpField> Fields { get; private set; }
    public List<CSharpProperty> Properties { get; private set; }
    ....
}
```

Collection of CShartpType in returned by:

```
   public List<CSharpType> TypeCollection
    {
        get
        {
            TypeCollection kolekcjaTypow = metricsCollection.Types;
            Dictionary<string, CSharpType> typy = kolekcjaTypow.TypeDictionary;
            var result = typy.Values.ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Every Field, Method, Property has a "Name" property
and I want to have TreeView (e.g):

```
Person
     + Fields
       + field1 name from Fields collection
       + field2 name from Fields collection
       ...
     + Methods
       ....
     + Properties
```

How sholud the xaml look like ? Thank for your help

Comment: Have you looked at the sample XAML at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx ?

Comment: Yes. That`s my TreeView:   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TypeCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TypeTemplate}">
                        </TreeView>

Answer (score 0):

If the classes are as follows:

```
public class FatherClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ChildClass> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in the ctor of the window I have the following data:

```
        List<FatherClass> list = new List<FatherClass>();

        list.Add(new FatherClass { Name = "First Father" });
        list.Add(new FatherClass { Name = "Second Father" });

        list[0].Children = new List<ChildClass>();
        list[1].Children = new List<ChildClass>();

        list[0].Children.Add(new ChildClass { Name = "FirstChild" });
        list[0].Children.Add(new ChildClass { Name = "SecondChild" });
        list[1].Children.Add(new ChildClass { Name = "ThirdChild" });
        list[1].Children.Add(new ChildClass { Name = "ForthChild" });

        this.DataContext = list;
```

then in order to create hierarchical databinding, you should define two hierarchical datatemplates in the resources to 'catch' the relevant data types, like so:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type  my:FatherClass}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ChildClass}"  >
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" />

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

and then, the syntax of the treeview should be:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding }">

    </TreeView>
```